# Run data.sql file after flyway migration

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, flyway

In my Spring boot project, I maintain `sql/query` version by `flyway`. For some reason, I need to load some of initial data which I don't wan to add on flyway version. For those data, I am creating related tables from `flyway` scripts. So to load initial data, I must run my `data.sql` file after flyway executes that scrips. How can I be sure to run my `data.sql` file after flyway runs its scrips?
Any suggestion please?

Comment: did you solve the problem?? I'm curious too 
because I don't want to write dummy data in flyway files.
just separate schema and data like that

Comment: you can try the solution written below. I was engaged to different task and hence couldn't try that solution. Initially I did some manual tasks to do my job

Comment: I see thank you for telling me :)

Answer (score 1):

`data.sql` gets ran automatically for embedded databases.

For MySQL you will need to add the following property to your `application.properties` file:

`spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always`

Edit:

To apply after Flyway has ran migrations you could use Flyway's repeatable migrations as they are always applied last. https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#repeatable-migrations

Or as another alternative you could use a `CommandLineRunner` and source and execute your SQL file programmatically. For example:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;

@Component
public class DatabaseMigration implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Value("classpath:data.sql")
  private Resource dataFile;

  @Override
  public void run(String... strings) {
    // read file and execute with JdbcTemplate
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response!  I know that, but my question is how to control the sequence of running the scripts i.e. flyway scripts and data.sql script stated above.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Example

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@Getter
public class FlywayConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.flyway.url}") private String link;
    @Value("${spring.flyway.user}") private String user;
    @Value("${spring.flyway.password}") private String password;
    @Value("${spring.flyway.table}") private String table;
    @Value("${spring.flyway.default-schema}") private String defaultSchema;
    @Value("${spring.flyway.schemas}") private String schemas;
    @Value("${migrate.target}") private String target;
}
```

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;

@Slf4j
@Component
@Getter
public class FlywayInstance {
    private final Flyway flyway;
    private final FlywayConfiguration flywayConfiguration;

    FlywayInstance(FlywayConfiguration flywayConfiguration) {
        FluentConfiguration flyway = Flyway.configure()
                .dataSource(flywayConfiguration.getLink(), flywayConfiguration.getUser(), flywayConfiguration.getPassword())
                .table(flywayConfiguration.getTable())
                .defaultSchema(flywayConfiguration.getDefaultSchema())
                .schemas(flywayConfiguration.getSchemas());

        if (!flywayConfiguration.getTarget().isBlank()) {
            flyway.target(flywayConfiguration.getTarget());
        }
//        flyway = flyway
//                .initSql("INSERT INTO base.data(name)\n" +
//                " VALUES ('bobo4');");

        this.flyway = flyway.load();

        this.flywayConfiguration = flywayConfiguration;
    }

    @PostConstruct()
    public void validateConnection() {
        log.info(String.format("Checking connection on startup for %s", this.flywayConfiguration.getLink()));
        log.info(String.format("Connected. Version: %s, Migrations: %d",
                flyway.info().getInfoResult().schemaVersion,
                flyway.info().getInfoResult().migrations.size()));
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    public boolean execute(String call) {
        final CallableStatement callableStatement = this.flyway
                .getConfiguration()
                .getDataSource()
                .getConnection()
                .prepareCall(call);
        return callableStatement.execute();
    }
}
```

With execute you can run ddl. At least table creation works for me.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is simply to use afterMigrate flyway callback. And put these tests data inserts in test/resources

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).